# Matlab: function on multiple files

Tags: matlab, function, file, wave

I want to read all wav files containing in a folder, for each file I perform a function.
The result of this function is a number. I want save several results in a file txt.

This is my code:

```
dirMask = 'folder\*.wav';  
wavRoot = fileparts(dirMask);

Files=dir(dirMask);

x = []; 

for k=1:length(Files)
    FileNames = fullfile(wavRoot, Files(k).name)
    nomi=FileNames;
    [s,fs] = audioread(FileNames);

 a = function(s, fs);

    x=a; 

end

fid = fopen('file.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid,'%f\n',x);
fclose(fid);
```

This code doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: The code "doesn't work" because...

Comment: It does not save all results but only the last four

Comment: All you're doing is changing the value of `x` every loop, then writing the final value at the end. I'm surprised it writes the last 4 and not the last 1. You need to either **1.** update `x` each loop using `x(end+1) = a` (there's better ways to do this, but whatever). You may need to change how you then use `fprintf`. **2.** use `fopen` before the loop, skip using `x` entirely, and use `fprintf(fid,'%f\n',a)` inside the loop. Side note: I assume you're not actually using `function` as a function  name? This is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

I rearranged things a bit. I wasn't entirely positive of the original intent but I think this is what you were trying to achieve:

```
dirMask = 'folder\*.wav';  
Files = dir(dirMask);
fid = fopen('file.txt','wt');

for k=1:length(Files)
   FileName = [ Files(k).folder '\' Files(k).name ]

   [s,fs] = audioread(FileName);

   % functions named function is a bad idea as it is keyword protected
   x = myFunction(s,fs);
   fprintf(fid,'%f\n',x);

end

fclose(fid);
```